# HTML - Is there a correct container element to place around table rows?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an HTML table, to which I would like to add or remove rows dynamically, using a select box with some basic javascript.

I am not adding single rows, but a group of similar rows at the same time.  For example, if I already had one set, then added another, the result would like like this:

```
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Item 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <td>X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Item 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <td>B</td>
</tr>
```

To add the rows, I am using jQuery's clone method, so I need some sort of container element to go around the group of rows, however, everything I have tried (span, div, etc) has led to invalid HTML and not functioned correctly.

The only way I have managed to get it working is to have each set as a separate table, but this isn't really the effect I want.

Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: Do you need to have a container around your rows? Having `tr` should be enough. Otherwise, you'll probably want to create `div`s for each row and column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could use `tbody`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 12):

[`<tbody>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-tbody-element.html#the-tbody-element) is the tag you’re looking for.

(And if your `<th>`s are headings for their group of table rows, you can also use the `scope` attribute to indicate this: `<th colspan="2" scope="rowgroup">`.)

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">Item 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Title</th>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Description</th>
      <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">Item 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Title</th>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Description</th>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note however that within the table, you must either put all `<tr>`s in a `<tbody>` (or `<thead>` or `<tfoot>`) element, or none of them.

I.e. this is valid:

```
<table>
    <!-- All <tr>s are inside <tbody>s -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this isn’t:

```
<table>
    <!-- <tr>s and <tbody>s can’t be siblings. -->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know the `tbody` element could be used multiple times within a table

Comment: @jasonscript: heck yes. And '<th scope="rowgroup">' creates a header cell that labels its parent `<tbody>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The [tbody element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `<tbody>` tag